# What does exactly "giacche" mean here?

Tags: soft-question, translation-request

While translating some Italian paper with Google translator of the following sentence

> Gli elementi di $G_\nu $, che godono la detta proprieta, formano evidentemente gruppo e questo gruppo, giacche contiene $G$, non puo coincidere col gruppo formato dall'elemento identico.

I found

> The elements of $G_\nu$, enjoying such properties, evidently formed group and this group, jackets contains $G$, can not coincide with the group formed by the same.

What does exactly "giacche" mean here? It is translating as "jackets".

Comment: Was the word not "giacché"?

Comment: Yes, now it is translating as "since G contains", but the translation of giacché is giving as "as". Is it "as G contains?"

Comment: "gruppo formato dall'elemento identico" <- that's "the group formed by the identity element", also known as the trivial group. "The elements ... evidently form a group, which, since it contains $G$, cannot be the trivial group."

Comment: I don't know: I am neither Italian nor an algebraist. However, I know that in certain languages **é** is not known and usually replaced by **e**.

Comment: Also proprietà should be written with an accent, but since proprieta doesn't exist in Italian google translated it correctly, on the other hand giacche and giacché are 2 different words and google was actually right in translating giacche as jackets

Comment: Maybe it's an advertising for jackets. The elements of $G_v$ seem to be enjoying their jackets!

Comment: It's quite old fashioned Italian; can you give a pointer to the paper?

Answer (score 5):

zoli has already answered the core of the question, but since the Google translation is so bad and misleading, here's a proper translation [with comments on the corrected parts]:

> Gli elementi di $G_\nu$, che godono la detta proprietà, formano
>   evidentemente gruppo e questo gruppo, giacché contiene $G$, non può
>   coincidere col gruppo formato dall'elemento identico.

The elements of $G_\nu$, which enjoy the said property [singular], evidently form [present tense] a group, and this group, since it contains $G$ [not the other way around], cannot coincide with the group formed by the identity [not same] element.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks for the missing accents. The definite article in front of "said" isn't required in English, though; "said property" is just as idiomatic.

Answer (score 4):

Taking the word "giacché" rather than taking "giacche" Google translate gave:

"The elements of $G_ \nu$, enjoying such properties, evidently formed group and this group, **since** $G$ contains, can not coincide with the group formed by the same."

Does this make any more sense?

Note that giacche=**jacket** and giacché = **since, as, if already** or something close to those.